# Unable to create external table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create external table in snowflake and it fails with the below error.

SQL compilation error: invalid property 'auto_refresh' for 'different storage type from cloud provider'"

Here are the queries which I am trying.

> CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE DEV_EXT_TABLE   WITH LOCATION =
> @XXX/dev1/metadata/   FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET SKIP_HEADER = 3);

and

> CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE DEV_EXT_TABLE   AUTO_REFRESH = TRUE
> WITH LOCATION = @XXX/dev1/metadata/   FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET
> SKIP_HEADER = 3);

My account is in AWS whereas stage in Google Cloud Platform and this seems to be supported.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-auto.html

Also does snowflake supports Auto refresh or not in cross deployments

Comment: Cross platform AutoRefresh is not supported. By this I mean external table created on AWS, should not have auto-refresh enabled, if the data is located on GCS or Azure.

Could you try the below and update if you are able to create the table or not.

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE DEV_EXT_TABLE AUTO_REFRESH = FALSE WITH LOCATION = @XXX/dev1/metadata/ FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET SKIP_HEADER = 3);

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the following:
=> My account is in AWS whereas the stage is in Google Cloud Platform and this seems to be supported.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-auto.html

The parameter controlling this feature has not been fully rolled out yet, however, documentation implies that the feature is GA which causes confusion.

Please open a case with Snowflake Support to have the parameter enabled to allow cross cloud auto refresh.

Additionally, SKIP_HEADER is the option for CSV type only not available for PARQUET.